# Independent linear forms question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N$ be a positive integer. Consider a family $\mathcal F_1=\{L_1\cdots,L_N\}$ of independent linear forms of $\mathcal L(\mathbb C^N,\mathbb C)$. Let $m<N$ be a positive integer and $\mathcal F_2=\{\Sigma_1,\cdots,\Sigma_m\}$ be a family of independent linear forms of $\mathcal L(\mathbb C^N,\mathbb C)$. I don't see why one can choose $N-m$ linear forms $L_{i_1},\cdots,L_{i_{N-m}}$ in $\mathcal F_1$ such that the family
$(L_{i_1},\cdots,L_{i_{N-m}})\cup\mathcal F_2$ is a basis of $\mathcal L(\mathbb C^N,\mathbb C)$.
Thanks in advance for any hints and answers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with linear forms. See number 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma#Statement). Note that $\mathcal F_1$ also spans $\mathcal L(\Bbb C^N,\Bbb C)$, since the latter has dimension $N$.

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I looked for.